# click go back arrow , from same activity back to different fragment"

Tags: android, fragment, toolbar

Iet's say I have 3 tabs,  i use slidingTabLayout
so 3 tabs are 3 fragments.
i use toolbar, so each fragment has toolbar with textview and icons.

for fragment 1 and 2, icon is the same "search icon", if click it, will go to another activity for searching something.

if user at "search activity" there is a "back arrow" on tool bar, click it, user should go back to previous fragment.

if user in fragment 1, and then he click "search" he go to "search activity", and after searching, he click "back arrow", he should go back to fragment 1.

but if user in fragment 2,  he click "search" he go to the same "search activity", and after searching, he click "back arrow", he should go back to fragment 2.

so i googled "click go back arrow , from same activity back to different fragment"

i did not find clue ...i think it might be something with "fragment Manager",  "backPressed"....i lost myself now

I guess i might not use the correct words for google.....

Answer (score 1):

I think this could work.
Have a searchable activity, a link for that is [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)

```
@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_search) {
        onSearchRequested();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

In the Search activity, have something like this in the OnCreate method:

```
  ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
```

And then also in the search activity

```
@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can be solved in `onBackPressed()` function.

It works like a back button.

You can try to add your arrow icon like this.

```
public void onClick() {
    onBackPressed();
}
```

Hope it helps.